# Google Maps: Position Ground Overlay

Tags: maps, overlay, positioning

I have some pictures that I want to overlay on Top of Google Maps.

My Problem is that I don´t know the exact Lat/Long for the top-left and the bottom-right edge of the images. Also I have to know the rotation.

Is there a tool where I can position a Image on top of Google Maps via GUI and which tells the the nesessary data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I´m using Google Earth for this